# Jquery mobile page cannot populate with data

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

**Index.html**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="reviewsPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Reviews</h1>
            <a href="twitter.html" id="twitterBtn" class="ui-btn-right"
            >TWEET</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#reviewsPage", function(event) {
            $("#twitterBtn").bind("click", function(e) {
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

                $.mobile.loadPage("twitter.html", {
                    reloadPage :false
                });

            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Above shows my index.html file which load the twitter.html file.

**twitter.html**

```
   <div data-role="page" id="twitterPage">

   <div data-role="content">
    <ul id="tweet-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">
            <p>
                Tweets
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#twitterPage" ).live("pagebeforecreate", function(){{
        alert("shdgs");
       $.ajax({
        url : " searchresult.php",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("dsds");
            var markup = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                var $template = $('<div><li><img class="ui-li-icon profile"><p class="from"></p><p class="tweet"></p></li></div>');
                $template.find(".from").append(elem['a']);
                //$template.find(".tweet").append(result.text);
                //$template.find(".profile").attr("src", result.profile_image_url);
                markup += $template.html();

            });
            $("#tweet-list").append(markup).listview("refresh", true);

            $.mobile.changePage($("#twitterPage"));
        },

        error : function(request, error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action
            alert(error);
        }
    });

});
```

When the index html calls the twitter.html file.The screen will be replaced with twiter.html w file without data.But if i run twitter.html directly data will be populated.

Comment: Please replace this `$( "#twitterPage" ).live("pagebeforecreate", function(){{` with `$( document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#twitterPage' ,function(){{`

Comment: still does not work.i tried in google chrome

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `href=twitter.html` to migrate to the twitter page. You are not really changing the page as JQM requires. Hence `pagebeforecreate` is not being called.

Comment: So can u tell me how to solve this

Comment: Are you ok with putting the two pages in the same html file? i can give you a quick solution..

Comment: sure tell me.actully i take this example from pro Jquery mobile book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the `body` of HTML file as:

```
<div data-role="page" id="reviewsPage">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Reviews</h1>
         <a id="twitterBtn" class="ui-btn-right">TWEET</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="twitterPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="tweet-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <p>Tweets</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In javaScipt code change `loadPage` to `changePage` (put the two js code in same file):

```
$("#twitterBtn").bind("click", function (e) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    $.mobile.changePage("#twitterPage", {
        reloadPage: false
    });

});
```

See this working version: http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/272/

Comment: your example works fine.But when the data is loaded to the next page and show on  list view and disapper

Comment: Must be some silly mistake you are making. I cannot tell why this happens, depends on your new code. Does not happen in my case: http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/273/

Comment: yeah i did some silly mistake.Cant i use load method to load the page faster.If can where should i put the code

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I think best is to close this question and continue discussion elsewhere.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience.Actually in my previous code i  use $.mobile.loadPage("twitter.html", {
                    reloadPage :false
                }); to speed up the app.In your code i donot know know where to put that part.pardon my English